# How to Generate Dynamic Xpath

Tags: java, xpath, selenium-webdriver

How to Generate Dynamic Xpath?
I)In my project all module's element pattern and location is same only that id is change as per module name

II)Id pattern in my project like this

Module-1

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//form[@id='locationForm']/div[2]/fieldset/table/tbody/tr[3]/td[2]/input"));
```

Module-2

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//form[@id='courtTypeBean']/div[2]/fieldset/table/tbody/tr[3]/td[2]/input"));
```

II)In this case can we make some standard or pattern that can we use in all module as common and by passing only id we can identify particular element?

like if i want to locate Module-1 element then i need to pass only id of ->locationForm, NOT this whole line

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//form[@id='locationForm']/div[2]/fieldset/table/tbody/tr[3]/td[2]/input"));
```

Comment: As parameter inside By.Xpath is String ,and you only want to change form id ,use String concatenation to generate desired String

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The xpath statement is a string, you can concatenate the string like this:

```
String passedId = "locationForm";

driver.findElement(By.xpath("//form[@id='" + passedId +"']/div[2]/fieldset/table/tbody/tr[3]/td[2]/input"));
```

Let me know if this is not what you are asking.  Thanks.

Comment: I'm not sure what facilities Selenium offers, but if you can, use parameters in your XPath expression rather than string concatenation. String concatenation leaves you very exposed to injection attacks. Write your XPath expression as `//form[@id=$param]/div[2]/....` and then bind a value to `$param` when executing it.